# Filament doesn't retract for some travel movements using PrusaSlicer

Tags: retraction, prusaslicer

The printer does not retract the filament for some travel moves result in scrape printing part as shown in picture.

[image]

This is my printer setting. Not sure which part be the problem.

[image]

I want my printer to retract the filament as I have set it to. Where to check and what could be the problem?

Comment: What is meant by "`result in scrape printing part`"?

Comment: The nozzle do rapid move and hit under layer. Sometimes the build plate shifted or the part popped out from bed.

Answer (score 1):

`Minimum Travel after Retraction` is exactly what it says on the tin: if the travel after a retraction would be less than 2 mm, it does *not* retract. You'll want that to be short, but not 0, because retraction can lead to under extrusion at the start of a new line, and every swap from one shell to the next shell right next to it is classed as travel.

Comment: I think so but you see somw travwl got very long distant but it still not retract which so confusing.

Comment: Set it to line width and see what happens?

Comment: 0.4 or slightly over should work fine.

Comment: Retraction does not cause underextrusion though; rather it's necessary to prevent it.

Comment: Okay then any way to make 3d printer just lift the nozzle up with no retraction?